# How to add id attribut in radio field yii2

Tags: yii2

I have created radiolist in yii2 like below.How to set id for the radiolist,
I have try like this:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'question')->radioList(['Y'=>'Yes','N'=>'No'],['id'=>'question'])->label('Any question'); ?>
```

but when i view the html source the id not in the radiolist field but in div

```
<div id="question" role="radiogroup">
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="MabaForm[question]" value="Y"> Yes</label> 
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="MabaForm[question]" value="N">No</label>
</div>
</div>
```

i want the id in radio input attribut like this

`<label><input type="radio" name="MabaForm[question]" value="Y" id="question"> Yes</label>`

any help? sory for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For radioList it's not super-easy because you need to provide callback for all the items and you don't want to have the same ID for every option because IDs must be unique, so something like:

```
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'question')
    ->radioList(
        ['Y' => 'Yes', 'N' => 'No'],
        ['item' => static function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) use ($model) {
            if ($label === 'Yes') {
                $id = 'id-for-yes';
            } else {
                $id = 'id-for-no';
            }
            return \yii\web\Html::radio(
                $name,
                $checked,
                [
                    'value' => $value,
                    'label' => $label,
                    'id' => $id
                ]
            );
        }]
    )
    ->label('Any question'); ?>
```

I'm not 100% sure I have all options here properly so check it first but this is general idea.